# How can I return the next row of WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql DB server ..
I have the following table that consists of only one column with the following data (where 0's separate sorted integers)

```
Number
-------
0 
1
2
3
0
4
5
0
6
7
8
0
9
10
0
11
```

I want to get the first value that comes after each 0 , so e.g. output would be

```
Output
------
1
4
6
9
11
```

Comment: "first value" as ordered by what? Rows in a relational database have no inherent order.

Comment: I basically need to know in which row numbers my values change from zero to non-zero value,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id1 FROM table WHERE id IN
(SELECT t1.id+1 FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.id1=t2.id 
WHERE t2.id1 IS NULL);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab8a/15)

Assuming no gaps in the increment field,but since it will be created..

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't guarantee a return order unless you specify a `ORDER BY` clause. If you get the values back in the order you insert them then that's just coincidence. As it stands there's no way to do what you want to do reliably. You need to add something to order the data by. An ID field set to `autoincrement` will probably do.

Comment: How can I append another column next to this column with the autoincremented ID that starts from 1?

Comment: This column is a result of union-ing two columns together in some way, I am certain that I'm going to get this pattern of data each time I do that union,,,,

Comment: @rida If you already have this data there's no way to guarantee that you'll number them in the right order. You need to create a new table and start again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add Auto_increment key to your table to guarantee order of records.

```
Alter table T ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

And here is the query:

```
select * from T as T1
Where (SELECT Number From T where Id<T1.Id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) = 0
order by ID
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/781e7/2)</kbd>